# Woocommerce rewrite rule for product sub category

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, woocommerce

Using this code here:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'products/([^/]*?)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'products/([^/]*?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
});
```

And having these permalink settings

**Product category base:** `products`
**Product permalink - custom base:** `/products/%product_cat%`

I get the following:

- `/products/%category_name%/` (Parent Product Category Page works fine).
- `/products/%category_name%/%subcategory_name/` (Child Product Category Page does not work - gets 404).
- `/products/%category_name%/%subcategory_name/%product_name` (Single Products works fine).

Anybody have any insight on how to get the Child Product Category pages to not throw the 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed these issue we should do some little changes in above code.

```html
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', function( $rules )
{
    $new_rules = array(
        'products/([^/]+?)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
        'products(?:/.*)*?/(<!--some-indentword-->-[^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $new_rules + $rules;
} ,20,1);
```

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thanks for answering this... doesn't work for me on WP 4.9.6, WooCom 3.4.3.

As per the OP Child Product Cat returns a 404.

I wonder I'm missing something, should I replace <!--some-indentword--> with my own text?

Comment: Ah, I realise I have a further complication as my Shop url ("Store") is also a Page titled Products. Perhaps I'll start a new thread.